# Howto daemonizing a while loop in bash?

Tags: bash

I would like to have a periodic check process launch from within a bash script, that checks some status:

```
# my script
somethings_to_do

# check every x seconds
background_check(){
while true;do
   sleep 300
   #stuff
done
}

background_check &
PID=$!
echo $PID > controlfile
```

I would like also to be able to control the process afterwards.

What is the best way to do this? Launch a while loop to the background and capture the PID for later use like in the above example?

Comment: Look into [systemd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) or [cron](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/configtuning-cron.html) perhaps?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But I am not using systemd on this system.

Comment: Rebuilding this wheel yourself is silly -- there's no shortage of tools already out there that do this job, and do it better. runit, daemontools, supervisord, and many many many more.

Comment: To be more specific about what I mean by "better" -- periodic polling is wildly inefficient compared letting the OS inform you immediately when a child process dies (and not at all before). Of course, if you want to do a proper periodic healthcheck in addition to watching for process death, serious process supervision frameworks do support that to -- but they also work hard on getting signal handling details right, which is a lot more interesting to try to do from a shell script.

Comment: That said -- if you _really_ want to know how to daemonize something in bash, be sure to disconnect all FDs attached to the controlling terminal (`background_check </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &`), and use `disown` if you're in a terminal with job control enabled (which is disabled by default in non-interactive shells). Still, though -- the better answer is to use tools built for the job.

Comment: (Also, capturing the PID to a file is a bad idea too -- PIDs get reused, after all; better to use advisory locking to see if something is still running -- which will never give you a false positive like checking the process table will -- and `fuser` to track down the processes holding the lock if/when you need the PID. The tools I mentioned above, since they take advantage of parent/child process relationship and wait only on their children, will never have these bugs).